# Animating vertical stepper with Tailwind

Tags: animation, tailwind-css, stepper

I'm super close to building out an animated vertical stepper in Tailwind, however, I cannot figure out how to make the height of each individual step match the height of the content while preserving the animation! I would have thought that h-fit (instead of h-16) would do the trick, but for some reason, the animation stops working in that case.

Functioning Sandbox can be found here! https://codesandbox.io/s/still-grass-8gxu0q?file=/src/App.tsx

Would greatly appreciate any help and insight you can provide!

Here is the section of code that's giving me trouble:

```
<div
    className={`overflow-y-hidden h-0 mt-5 transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 flex flex-col border border-white ${
      stepIdx === currentStep ? "h-16" : ""
    }`}
  >
    <div
      className={`${
        isCurrent(stepIdx) ? "text-white" : "text-gray-500"
      } mb-5`}
    >
      {step.description}
    </div>
  </div>
  {isCurrent(stepIdx) ? (
    <Buttons handleNext={handleNext} handleBack={handleBack} />
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! CSS does not recommend using non-fixed heights in animations; however, the workaround is to instead use max-height.

Here's a working Sandbox in case anyone in the future needs help: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-grass-8gxu0q?file=/src/App.tsx